# Как округлить углы выделенной рамки QComboBox?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qss, qcombobox

Мне нужно сделать скругление для выбранного элемента, как я показал на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.comboBox = QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet(''' 
 QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    outline: 0px;
}''')

        self.comboBox.addItem("1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("3")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update**:

Видимо я не полностью объяснил проблему, в вашем случае, я бы хотел, чтобы внутри рамки тоже было залито каким-то цветом. Это возможно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                         # !!! +++
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")                # !!! +++
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                        # !!! +++

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.addItems(["1", "2", "3"])

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv       
        self.comboBox.view().window().setWindowFlags(
            QtCore.Qt.Popup | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.comboBox.view().window().setAttribute(
            QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)


StyleSheet = '''
QWidget {
    background-color: #18465d;
}

QComboBox {
    font: 18pt Fira Sans Condensed;     
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    border-top: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-left: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-right: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3e3e3e;
    padding: 5%;
    max-height: 30px;
    min-width: 140px;
    color: white;
    selection-background-color: #5e5e5e;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

QComboBox::drop-down {
    border: none;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(down-arrow.png);
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:pressed {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px; left: 1px;
}

QComboBox QListView {
    background-color: transparent;              
    outline: 2px solid red;     
    color: white;
    selection-background-color: #18465d;  
    padding: 5%;
    outline-radius: 12px;            
}

QComboBox:editable {
    background-color : red;  
} 
 
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border : 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 15px;      
}

'''
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                                      # +++
    
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(200, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**:

> Видимо я не полностью объяснил проблему в вашем случае я бы хотел, чтобы внутри рамки тоже было залито каким то цветом. Это возможно сделать?

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()        
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)        
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.addItems([" 1", " Hello World", " 3"])
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
     
        self.comboBox.view().window().setWindowFlags(
            QtCore.Qt.Popup | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.comboBox.view().window().setAttribute(
            QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    

StyleSheet = '''
QWidget {
    background-color: #18465d;
}

QComboBox {
    font: 18pt Fira Sans Condensed;     
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    border-top: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-left: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-right: 0px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3e3e3e;
    padding: 5%;
    max-height: 30px;
    min-width: 140px;
    color: white;
    selection-background-color: #5e5e5e;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

QComboBox::drop-down {
    border: none;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(down-arrow.png);
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:pressed {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px; left: 1px;
}

QComboBox QListView {
    background-color: transparent;  
    outline: 2px solid red;     
    color: white;

/*     
    selection-background-color: #18465d; 
    
    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        */
    selection-background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1,
                    stop:0 rgba(24, 70, 93, 255), 
                    stop:0.1 rgba(24, 70, 93, 255),
                    stop:0.2 rgba(24, 70, 93, 255),
                    stop:0.3 rgba(0, 155, 255, 255),
                    stop:0.4 rgba(0, 200, 255, 255), 
                    stop:0.5 rgba(0, 230, 255, 255),
                    stop:0.6 rgba(0, 200, 255, 255),
                    stop:0.7 rgba(0, 155, 255, 255),
                    stop:0.8 rgba(24, 70, 93, 255),
                    stop:0.9 rgba(24, 70, 93, 255),
                    stop:1 rgba(24, 70, 93, 255));  
/*  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        */   
    padding: 5%;
    outline-radius: 12px;            
}

QComboBox:editable {
    background-color : red;  
} 
 
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border : 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 15px;      
}
'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(200, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да это полезно. Но видимо я не полностью объяснил проблему в вашем случае я бы хотел, чтобы внутри рамки тоже было залито каким то цветом. Это возможно сделать?

Comment: @MIkhail я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: @MIkhail что не так?

Comment: это странное заполнение: оно выходит за рамки (пиксели видно)

Comment: @MIkhail это нормальное заполнение и у меня ничего и никуда не выходит. Но если для вас это странно - пусть будет так.

Comment: @MIkhail вы до сих пор считаете это странным заполнением?

Comment: Я бы хотел видеть полное заполнение одним цветом по границам